# Dual monitors Ubuntu low resolution

Tags: ubuntu, display, multiple-monitors, nvidia

I have dual monitor setup works with Ubuntu as OS, It was working perfectly and suddenly one of the monitor stopped working and the second one is working with low resolution of 1024×768, with no option to change it, when I disconnect the working monitor the second one starts working in the same low resolution, the monitors are LG 4K, and the graphic card is GTX1060 6GB, I tried change the driver of the GPU but still not working, any one can help?
Can it be a problem of GPU?

Comment: Ubuntu release/version? Which Nvidia driver? It should be 535.x at the time of this comment. Did this happen after a recent system update? If so, which kernel version are you running currently? Have you tried booting with a older kernel? Please [edit] the question accordingly, avoid giving requested info only in comments.